# Ideas to optimize this data comparison from base to base?

Tags: java, database, performance, optimization, compare

I wrote a little java (jdk1.8) class to compare data between two databases : one request get rows from source DB, then multitasks search each row in target DB (each thread get its own connection and preparedstatement).

The code below is ok (I just remove some logs, passwords, and some catch exceptions), for example I compare 28.700.000 rows, for a table with 140 columns, from DB2 to same table in Oracle, in 3 hours. Not incredible, but correct, I think ;).

So if you have some ideas to optimize this code, I take ideas :)

```
public class CompareDB {

    public static AtomicInteger nbRowEqual = new AtomicInteger();
    public static AtomicInteger nbRowNotFound = new AtomicInteger();
    public static AtomicInteger nbRowDiff = new AtomicInteger();
    public static AtomicInteger nbRowErr = new AtomicInteger();
    public static List<PreparedStatement> targetPstmtPool = new ArrayList<PreparedStatement>();
    public static final String[] columns = {"id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"};

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int MAX_THREAD = 200, position = 0;
        Integer targetPstmtNumber;
        List<Connection> targetConnectionPool = new ArrayList<Connection>();
        long beginExecTime = System.currentTimeMillis(), startReqTime;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // Create connection + preparedStatement pools to target DB
        System.out.println("Start opening connections");
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_THREAD; i++) {
            Connection targetConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<dbname>", "<user>", "<password>");
            targetConn.setAutoCommit(false);
            targetConn.setReadOnly(true);
            targetConnectionPool.add(targetConn);
            PreparedStatement targetPstmt = targetConn.prepareStatement("select "+String.join(",", columns)+" from mytable where id=?");
            targetPstmtPool.add(targetPstmt);
        }

        // Connect + select from source DB
        Connection sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://<IP>:<port>/<dbname>", "<user>", "<password>");
        sourceConn.setAutoCommit(false);
        sourceConn.setReadOnly(true);
        Statement sourceStmt = sourceConn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet sourceResult = sourceStmt.executeQuery("select "+String.join(",", columns)+ " from owner.mytable");

        System.out.println("Connections and statements opened in "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-beginExecTime)+" ms");

        // Open pool of threads
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 20, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
        CompletionService<Integer> completion = new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executor);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Start compare data ("+MAX_THREAD+" parallel threads)");
        System.out.println();
        startReqTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // For each row of the source request
        while (sourceResult.next()) {
            // Set which pstmt to give to thread
            if (position < MAX_THREAD) targetPstmtNumber = new Integer(position);
            else                       targetPstmtNumber = completion.take().get();

            // extract values from resultSet as parameter for next thread
            List<Object> sourceRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (int i=1; i<=columns.length; i++) {
                sourceRow.add(sourceResult.getObject(i));
            }

            // Call thread
            completion.submit(new CompareDbThread(sourceRow, targetPstmtNumber));

            position++;
            if (position % 10000 == 0) System.out.println("  -- "+position+" rows --");
            else if (position % 100 == 0) System.out.print(".");
        }

        // Await for last threads
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Waiting last threads...");
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();

        // Close all Rs, Stmt, Conn
        try {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Close all requests, statements, connections");
            for (PreparedStatement targetPstmt : targetPstmtPool) targetPstmt.close();
            for (Connection targetConn : targetConnectionPool) targetConn.close();
            sourceResult.close();
            sourceStmt.close();
            sourceConn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[INFO] Error closing connections and requests : "+e.getMessage());
        } 

        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Data comparison done in "+(dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-startReqTime)))
                          +" : "+nbRowEqual+" equals, "+nbRowNotFound+" not found, "+nbRowDiff+" diff, "+nbRowErr+" ERROR rows");
        System.out.println("Threads : getCompletedTaskCount() = "+executor.getCompletedTaskCount()+", getTaskCount() = "+executor.getTaskCount());
        System.out.println("Total time : "+(dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-beginExecTime))));
    }
}


public class CompareDbThread implements Callable<Integer> {
    protected List<Object> sourceRow;
    protected Integer targetPstmtNumber;

    public CompareDbThread(List<Object> sourceRow, Integer targetPstmtNumber) {
        this.sourceRow = sourceRow;
        this.targetPstmtNumber = targetPstmtNumber;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        ResultSet targetResult;
        Object sourceColumnValue, targetColumnValue;
        String sSourceColumnValue, sTargetColumnValue;
        Double dSourceColumnValue, dTargetColumnValue;
        boolean equalRow=true, equalColumn=true;
        String message="", tempMessage="";

        try {
            PreparedStatement targetPstmt = CompareDB.targetPstmtPool.get(targetPstmtNumber.intValue());
            targetPstmt.setObject(1, sourceRow.get(0));
            targetResult = targetPstmt.executeQuery();
            if (targetResult.next()) {
                // Compare each column
                for (int i=0; i<CompareDB.columns.length; i++) {
                    sourceColumnValue = sourceRow.get(i);
                    targetColumnValue = targetResult.getObject(i+1);

                    if ((sourceColumnValue!=null && targetColumnValue==null) || (sourceColumnValue==null && targetColumnValue!=null)) {
                        equalRow=false;
                        message += CompareDB.columns[i] + " : " + targetColumnValue + "(au lieu de " + sourceColumnValue + "), "; 
                    }
                    else if (sourceColumnValue!=null && targetColumnValue!=null) {
                        // Compare as objects ...
                        if (!sourceColumnValue.equals(targetColumnValue)) {
                            sSourceColumnValue=sourceColumnValue.toString();
                            sTargetColumnValue=targetColumnValue.toString();

                            // if differents, compare as string ...
                            if (!sSourceColumnValue.equals(sTargetColumnValue)) {
                                tempMessage = CompareDB.columns[i] + " [String] : " + sTargetColumnValue + "(instead of " + sSourceColumnValue + "), ";
                                // if differents as string, compare as double
                                try {
                                    dSourceColumnValue = new Double(sSourceColumnValue);
                                    dTargetColumnValue = new Double(sTargetColumnValue);
                                    if (!dSourceColumnValue.equals(dTargetColumnValue)) {
                                        tempMessage = CompareDB.columns[i] + " [Number] : " + dTargetColumnValue + "(instead of " + dSourceColumnValue + "), ";

                                        equalColumn=false;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    equalColumn=false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!equalColumn) {
                            message += tempMessage;
                            tempMessage = "";
                            equalColumn=true;
                            equalRow=false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (equalRow) {
                    CompareDB.nbRowEqual.incrementAndGet();
                }
                else {
                    CompareDB.nbRowDiff.incrementAndGet();
                    System.out.println("  [DIFFERENT] ["+CompareDB.columns[CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS]+"="+sourceRow.get(CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS)+"] => "+message);
                }
            }
            else {
                CompareDB.nbRowNotFound.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("  [NOT FOUND] ["+CompareDB.columns[CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS]+"="+sourceRow.get(CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS)+"]");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            CompareDB.nbRowErr.incrementAndGet();
            System.err.println("[ERROR] "+CompareDB.columns[CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS]+"="+sourceRow.get(CompareDB.ID_COLUMN_POS)+" : "+e.getMessage());
        }

        return targetPstmtNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to traverse the result set in both directions don't use the scroll insensitive option, use the forwards only option as it's more performant.

Comment: You can also increase the fetch size of the result set to reduce the number of round-trips to the databases to get the next set of results (the oracle driver batches in groups of 10 iirc), this will improve performance at the cost of needing more memory to hold the results.

Comment: Thanks JonK, I replaced `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` with `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, and compared two launch, with 100.000 rows. Time is similar (between 1:53 and 1:55 min). Then, I added (just after call of sourceResult) : `sourceResult.setFetchSize(200);` and now, time is 2:00 :)... I will launch again with more rows, to see if it is significant ?

Comment: Try setting the fetch size on the PreparedStatements before you execute them rather than afterwards, as it'll go back to the DB to fetch the other 190 rows after getting the first 10

Comment: I made some tests with différents values or more rows, but no real gain of performance, even slower ;). By default, fetch size is equal 0, I didn't really find what does it mean ? is it 1 by 1 ? ou 10 by 10 ? or the best value ? or max ? or a default internal value of the jdbc driver ?

Comment: (for information, i use as source a **JDBC DB2 driver** : "DSN12010 ; IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ ; version **3.69.24**", and for target : "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production ; **Oracle JDBC driver** ; version **12.2.0.1.0**")